# Querying for DB Users who have a certain privilege e.g: SESSION privilege

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to query for DB Users who have a certain privilege like SESSION or CREATE TABLE privilege, any privilege whatsoever.

I couldn't wrap my head around on how to look for the privilege in all possible tables at once.

For example: The user 'user01' may not have direct table privileges but he may have them through his role.

How would you query for the possession of a direct and indirect specific privilege that you would check for with where privilege='such and such privilege'.

This is the idea I have so far

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_WHO_HAS_PRIVILEGE(arg_priv varchar2)
IS

CURSOR grantee_cur IS

SELECT   GRANTEE FROM DBA_SYS_PRIVS WHERE PRIVILEGE=arg_priv
UNION
SELECT   DISTINCT GRANTEE FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE PRIVILEGE=arg_priv
UNION
SELECT   GRANTEE FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS WHERE GRANTED_ROLE IN
         ( SELECT ROLE FROM ROLE_SYS_PRIVS WHERE PRIVILEGE = arg_priv)
UNION
SELECT   GRANTEE FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS WHERE GRANTED_ROLE IN
         (SELECT ROLE FROM ROLE_TAB_PRIVS WHERE PRIVILEGE = arg_priv);

BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Grantees: ');
FOR rec IN grantee_cur LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.grantee);
END LOOP;
END;
/

BEGIN
SP_WHO_HAS_PRIVILEGE(&priv);
END;

/
```

Not sure if this is the right answer or not..

Answer (score 0):

the thing you are trying to achieve can't be done by one parameter ,you need to build the procedure with either two parameters  privilege and username  or do it in steps.
e.g the following procedure will give you all the users and roles that owns the privilege you are looking for , then from that list you can pick the user you want to audit and look for his specific privileges in the same three views namely DBA_TAB_PRIVS , DBA_SYS_PRIVS and DBA_ROLE_PRIVS.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_WHO_HAS_PRIVILEGE(arg_priv varchar2)
IS
CURSOR grantee_cur IS SELECT   GRANTEE FROM DBA_SYS_PRIVS WHERE PRIVILEGE=arg_priv
UNION all
SELECT   DISTINCT GRANTEE FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE PRIVILEGE=arg_priv
UNION all
SELECT   GRANTEE FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS WHERE GRANTED_ROLE = arg_priv;

BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Grantees: ');
FOR rec IN grantee_cur LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.grantee);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```